# Duplicate statement of series/number when using @incollection with bibtex-mla

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

Consider this database entry:

```
@incollection{catani,
    author = {Stephanie Catani},
    title = {Kultur in der Krise},
    subtitle = {Zur Konstruktion von Männlichkeit bei Alfred Döblin und Robert Musil},
    booktitle = {Masculinities in German Culture},
    editor = {Sarah Colvin and Peter Davies},
    publisher = {Camden House},
    location = {Rochester},
    date = {2008},
    pages = {149--169},
    series = {Edinburgh German Yearbook},
    number = {2},
}
```

How can I make `biblatex-mla` cite this as:

> Catani, Stephanie. “Kultur in der Krise: Zur Konstruktion von Männlichkeit bei Alfred Döblin und Robert Musil”. *Masculinities in German Culture.* Eds. Sarah Colvin and Peter Davies. Rochester: Camden House, 2008. 149–169. Print. Edinburgh German Yearbook 2.

Because what `biblatex-mla` returns to me by standard is:

> Catani, Stephanie. “Kultur in der Krise: Zur Konstruktion von Männlichkeit bei Alfred Döblin und Robert Musil”. *Masculinities in German Culture.* Eds. Sarah Colvin and
>   Peter Davies. Edinburgh German Yearbook 2. Rochester: Camden House, 2008. 149–169.
>   Print. Edinburgh German Yearbook 2.

The series and number should only appear after "Print", not where the volume information would usually go. Seems like yet another bug in `biblatex-mla`.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be in `mla.bbx`, ll. 614–615. I copied the definition for `mla:incollection:internal` (`mla.bbx`, ll. 588–634) into my `.tex` file now – of course as `\renewbibmacro*{…}` – without those two lines and the citation is generated how it's supposed to, but I am still wondering if there's a less "wordy" way?

Comment: Put it in a file called `mlafix.sty`, load it after your normal `biblatex` stuff, and contact the maintainer about the issue.  You can also (probably) use `xpatch`'s `\xpatchbibmacro`, but without an MWE to work with....

Comment: You can try with the `xpatch` package and `\xpatchbibmacro{mla:incollection:internal}{\usebibmacro{series+number}}{}{}{}`

Comment: @jon, the thing is, `biblatex-mla` appears to be abandoned at the moment – [its Github repo](https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/) hasn't received any changes in 19 months. Someone even pushed a merge request to fix a bug related to my question, but nothing has happened so far.

Comment: Fair enough.  If there's no progress being made on the package, `\xpatchbibmacro` can be a tidy solution for simple changes.